# rake sunspot:solr:reindex not working in Rails 4 app with multiple engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have rails 4 beta1 application with multiple engines. I've installed sunspot_rails gem /2.0.0.pre.130115/ in my host application. Most of my models lived in engine1. I used them on other engines. After I installed sunspot_rails, using `rake sunspot:solr:run` I got `command/task not found`. According to documentation I found a solution. Here is the link: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Adding-Sunspot-search-to-Rails-in-5-minutes-or-less

After I created a new record Solr found it in a search. But when I reindexed my data, old records were still not found through a search. In my opinion reindex has not worked. I've tried stopping and restarting solr server, restarted my pc few times but no luck. Any idea?

If you need more info let me know.

Here are my gems:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.0.0.beta1)
  * actionpack (4.0.0.beta1)
  * activemodel (4.0.0.beta1)
  * activerecord (4.0.0.beta1)
  * activerecord-deprecated_finders (0.0.3)
  * activesupport (4.0.0.beta1)
  * admin (0.0.1)
  * arel (4.0.0.beta2)
  * atomic (1.1.7)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
  * builder (3.1.4)
  * bundler (1.3.2)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.0.beta1)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
  * core (0.0.1)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * factory_girl (4.2.0)
  * factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
  * fattr (2.2.1)
  * frontend (0.0.1)
  * highline (1.6.18)
  * hike (1.2.2)
  * i18n (0.6.4)
  * jbuilder (1.0.2)
  * jquery-rails (2.2.1)
  * json (1.7.7)
  * kaminari (0.14.1)
  * mail (2.5.3)
  * mime-types (1.22)
  * minitest (4.7.1)
  * multi_json (1.7.2)
  * nokogiri (1.5.9)
  * options (2.3.0)
  * pg (0.15.1)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * pr_geohash (1.0.0)
  * progress_bar (1.0.0)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (4.0.0.beta1)
  * rails-i18n (0.7.3 1fc01d5)
  * railties (4.0.0.beta1)
  * rake (10.0.4)
  * rdoc (3.12.2)
  * rsolr (1.0.9)
  * sass (3.2.7)
  * sass-rails (4.0.0.beta1)
  * sprockets (2.9.2)
  * sprockets-rails (2.0.0.rc3)
  * store_admin (0.0.1)
  * store_frontend (0.0.1)
  * sunspot (2.0.0.pre.130115)
  * sunspot_rails (2.0.0.pre.130115)
  * sunspot_solr (2.0.0.pre.130115)
  * thor (0.18.1)
  * thread_safe (0.1.0)
  * tilt (1.3.7)
  * treetop (1.4.12)
  * tzinfo (0.3.37)
  * uglifier (2.0.1)
```

Manually generated solr task:

```
namespace :sunspot do
  namespace :solr do
    desc 'Start the Solr instance'
    task :start => :environment do
      case RUBY_PLATFORM
      when /w(in)?32$/, /java$/
        abort("This command is not supported on #{RUBY_PLATFORM}. " +
              "Use rake sunspot:solr:run to run Solr in the foreground.")
      end

      if defined?(Sunspot::Rails::Server)
        Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.start
      else
        Sunspot::Solr::Server.new.start
      end

      puts "Successfully started Solr ..."
    end

    desc 'Run the Solr instance in the foreground'
    task :run => :environment do
      if defined?(Sunspot::Rails::Server)
        Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.run
      else
        Sunspot::Solr::Server.new.run
      end
    end

    desc 'Stop the Solr instance'
    task :stop => :environment do
      case RUBY_PLATFORM
      when /w(in)?32$/, /java$/
        abort("This command is not supported on #{RUBY_PLATFORM}. " +
              "Use rake sunspot:solr:run to run Solr in the foreground.")
      end

      if defined?(Sunspot::Rails::Server)
        Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.stop
      else
        Sunspot::Solr::Server.new.stop
      end

      puts "Successfully stopped Solr ..."
    end

    # for backwards compatibility
    task :reindex => :"sunspot:reindex"
  end
end
```

My model:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  ##
  # Sunspot
  searchable auto_index: true, auto_remove: true do
    text :name, boost: 5
    text :description, boost: 4
    # integer :store_id
  end
end
```

And finally solr's schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<!--
 This is the Solr schema file. This file should be named "schema.xml" and
 should be in the conf directory under the solr home
 (i.e. ./solr/conf/schema.xml by default) 
 or located where the classloader for the Solr webapp can find it.

 This example schema is the recommended starting point for users.
 It should be kept correct and concise, usable out-of-the-box.

 For more information, on how to customize this file, please see
 http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml

 PERFORMANCE NOTE: this schema includes many optional features and should not
 be used for benchmarking.  To improve performance one could
  - set stored="false" for all fields possible (esp large fields) when you
    only need to search on the field but don't need to return the original
    value.
  - set indexed="false" if you don't need to search on the field, but only
    return the field as a result of searching on other indexed fields.
  - remove all unneeded copyField statements
  - for best index size and searching performance, set "index" to false
    for all general text fields, use copyField to copy them to the
    catchall "text" field, and use that for searching.
  - For maximum indexing performance, use the StreamingUpdateSolrServer
    java client.
  - Remember to run the JVM in server mode, and use a higher logging level
    that avoids logging every request
-->
<schema name="sunspot" version="1.0">
  <types>
    <!-- field type definitions. The "name" attribute is
       just a label to be used by field definitions.  The "class"
       attribute and any other attributes determine the real
       behavior of the fieldType.
         Class names starting with "solr" refer to java classes in the
       org.apache.solr.analysis package.
    -->
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="rand" class="solr.RandomSortField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->

    <!-- ANALYZERS -->

    <!-- ENGLISH ANALYZER -->
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="100" side="front"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>



    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- A specialized field for geospatial search. If indexed, this fieldType must not be multivalued. -->
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
  </types>
  <fields>
    <!-- Valid attributes for fields:
     name: mandatory - the name for the field
     type: mandatory - the name of a previously defined type from the
       <types> section
     indexed: true if this field should be indexed (searchable or sortable)
     stored: true if this field should be retrievable
     compressed: [false] if this field should be stored using gzip compression
       (this will only apply if the field type is compressable; among
       the standard field types, only TextField and StrField are)
     multiValued: true if this field may contain multiple values per document
     omitNorms: (expert) set to true to omit the norms associated with
       this field (this disables length normalization and index-time
       boosting for the field, and saves some memory).  Only full-text
       fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.
     termVectors: [false] set to true to store the term vector for a
       given field.
       When using MoreLikeThis, fields used for similarity should be
       stored for best performance.
     termPositions: Store position information with the term vector.  
       This will increase storage costs.
     termOffsets: Store offset information with the term vector. This 
       will increase storage costs.
     default: a value that should be used if no value is specified
       when adding a document.
   -->
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="id" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="type" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="class_name" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="text" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="lat" stored="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="lng" stored="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="random_*" stored="false" type="rand" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="_local*" stored="false" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_text" stored="false" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_texts" stored="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_b" stored="false" type="boolean" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_bm" stored="false" type="boolean" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_bs" stored="true" type="boolean" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_bms" stored="true" type="boolean" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_d" stored="false" type="date" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dm" stored="false" type="date" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ds" stored="true" type="date" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dms" stored="true" type="date" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_e" stored="false" type="sdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_em" stored="false" type="sdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_es" stored="true" type="sdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ems" stored="true" type="sdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_f" stored="false" type="sfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fm" stored="false" type="sfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fs" stored="true" type="sfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fms" stored="true" type="sfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_i" stored="false" type="sint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_im" stored="false" type="sint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_is" stored="true" type="sint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ims" stored="true" type="sint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_l" stored="false" type="slong" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_lm" stored="false" type="slong" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ls" stored="true" type="slong" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_lms" stored="true" type="slong" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_s" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_sm" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ss" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_sms" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_it" stored="false" type="tint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_itm" stored="false" type="tint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_its" stored="true" type="tint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_itms" stored="true" type="tint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ft" stored="false" type="tfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ftm" stored="false" type="tfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fts" stored="true" type="tfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ftms" stored="true" type="tfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dt" stored="false" type="tdate" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dtm" stored="false" type="tdate" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dts" stored="true" type="tdate" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dtms" stored="true" type="tdate" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_textv" stored="false" termVectors="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_textsv" stored="true" termVectors="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_et" stored="false" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_etm" stored="false" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ets" stored="true" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_etms" stored="true" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- Type used to index the lat and lon components for the "location" FieldType -->
    <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <dynamicField name="*_ll" stored="false" type="location" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_llm" stored="false" type="location" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_lls" stored="true" type="location" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_llms" stored="true" type="location" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
  </fields>
  <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness.
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
  <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
  <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field differently,
        or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster searching.  -->
</schema>
```

Comment: Are you specifying the correct environment when reindexing? Can you look at the Solr index files? Do you get any errors when reindexing? Reindex should show you the number of records, progress bar and time remaining, etc. Does it?

Comment: Try without the `solr` instruction. Just `rake sunspot:reindex` - That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue and the solution is to run the reindex with `bundle exec rake` not just `rake`

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop 
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start 
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
```