# Rails sunspot error on sunspot:solr:start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, sunspot

I'm actually trying to install and use the Sunspot gem for Rails (https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot). So far here is what I did. I added the dependencies in my `Gemfile` :

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
```

Then I did run `bundle` and create the configuration file using `rails generate sunspot_rails:install`. So far so good.

But then, when I tried to run `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`, I'm facing the following error :

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'sunspot:solr:start'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:148:in `invoke_task'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/project/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm actually using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0.0. Did anyone already face the same issue or know a way to fix that?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error that I was able to solve by adding the following file.

[Source of Rakefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251707/rake-sunspotsolrreindex-not-working-in-rails-4-app-with-multiple-engines) 
[Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647963/rake-sunspotsolrstart-throwing-an-error)

```
lib/tasks/solr.rake

namespace :sunspot do
  namespace :solr do
  desc 'Start the Solr instance'
    task :start => :environment do
      case RUBY_PLATFORM
        when /w(in)?32$/, /java$/
          abort("This command is not supported on #{RUBY_PLATFORM}. " +
          "Use rake sunspot:solr:run to run Solr in the foreground.")
     end

  if defined?(Sunspot::Rails::Server)
    Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.start
  else
    Sunspot::Solr::Server.new.start
  end
  puts "Successfully started Solr ..."
end

desc 'Run the Solr instance in the foreground'
task :run => :environment do
  if defined?(Sunspot::Rails::Server)
    Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.run
  else
    Sunspot::Solr::Server.new.run
  end
end

desc 'Stop the Solr instance'
task :stop => :environment do
  case RUBY_PLATFORM
  when /w(in)?32$/, /java$/
    abort("This command is not supported on #{RUBY_PLATFORM}. " +
          "Use rake sunspot:solr:run to run Solr in the foreground.")
  end

  if defined?(Sunspot::Rails::Server)
    Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.stop
  else
    Sunspot::Solr::Server.new.stop
  end
  puts "Successfully stopped Solr ..."
end

# for backwards compatibility
task :reindex => :"sunspot:reindex"
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try updating your version of the sunspot_solr gem, in case Rubygems is giving you an older version of sunspot_solr by mistake.

Try adding this to your gemfile instead of `gem 'sunspot_solr'` and running the `bundle install` + `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`:

```
gem 'sunspot_solr', '~> 2.0.0', group: :development
```